# Does any C or C++ standard recognize the existence of memory mapped files?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, memory-mapped-files

I just wondered whether it is at all possible to use memory mapped files in portable C or C++. I think not because as far as I know no standard recognizes the existence of memory mapped files.

Using memory mappings it is possible to have the same byte at two addresses. Also, I think it is not possible to even use a piece of memory without constructing an object there first (except through `char*`). So if we want to treat an existing mapped file as an array of integers that should be undefined behavior.

So what's the situation regarding memory mapped files and the standard?

Comment: No there's no notion about _memory mapped files_ in standards AFAIK.

Comment: Searching the C++14 standard for *memory mapped* gives 0 results.

Comment: You can use the memory allocated by `malloc()` as an array of whatever type you want (provided the allocation is large enough), see C11 draft standard n1570, *6.5 Expressions 6 effective type*. There is no reason you shouldn't be able to do the same with memory allocated by `mmap()`.

Comment: [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) does. As it is the standard that governs many OS interfaces (directories, files, and so on), and most current operating systems (just about all, except Windows of course -- although even Microsoft just announced some kind of support in cooperation with Canonical -- so although it is not *the* C standard, it is the most portable standard (IEEE Std 1003.1, to be exact) that governs such OS level interfaces in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do not. Memory mapping is generally offered by operating systems: C and C++ can also run without one. Imposing such availability on the range of platforms the languages target would be very limiting.

Files may also not be supported at all in freestanding environments, let alone memory mapped ones.

Answer (score 6):

> I just wondered whether it is at all possible to use memory mapped files in portable C or C++.

Yes it is (in c++), see the boost.interprocess library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file

> I think not because as far as I know no standard recognizes the existence of memory mapped files.

no it's not in a standard, it's in the boost library, which is almost as portable.

> Using memory mappings it is possible to have the same byte at two addresses. Also, I think it is not possible to even use a piece of memory without constructing an object there first (except through char*). So if we want to treat an existing mapped file as an array of integers that should be undefined behavior.

See the documentation above. You'll find that c++ objects map right into the shared memory, but are addressed through special 'offset' pointers from the beginning of the mapped memory region.

> So what's the situation regarding memory mapped files and the standard?

There is no situation. They're not part of the standard memory model.